# Parsing a JSON String with serde_json

Tags: redis, rust, serde-json

```
pub fn rust_server() -> redis::RedisResult<()> {
    println!("-> redis_server");
    let client = redis::Client::open(get_uri())?;
    let mut con = client.get_connection()?;

    println!("-> redis_server: {}", get_uri());

    println!("-> redis_server_pub_sub");
    let mut pub_sub = con.as_pubsub();

    println!("-> redis_server subscribe channels: {}", get_sub());
    pub_sub.subscribe(get_sub())?;

    loop {
        let msg = pub_sub.get_message()?;
        let payload: String = msg.get_payload()?;

        println!("{}", payload);
    }
}
```

How can I parse the following `JSON` payload of type `String` with `serde_json`?

```rust
let payload: String = msg.get_payload()?;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert `payload` of type `String` (JSON?) into something that allows you to access its values?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use [`serde_json::from_str`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.94/serde_json/fn.from_str.html) and it's well documented:

> ```rust
> use serde::Deserialize;
>
> #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
> struct User {
>     fingerprint: String,
>     location: String,
> }
>
> fn main() {
>     // The type of `j` is `&str`
>     let j = "
>         {
>             \"fingerprint\": \"0xF9BA143B95FF6D82\",
>             \"location\": \"Menlo Park, CA\"
>         }";
>
>     let u: User = serde_json::from_str(j).unwrap();
>     println!("{:#?}", u);
> }
> ```

Comment: No, this is for `str` not `String`.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You realize you can use a function that takes `&str` with `String`s, too, just add a reference. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)

Comment: I did not know that. Then what is the point of `as_str()` ?

Comment: [Type coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) only works when the target type is known, that's not always the case.